# Function changes in the new sdk aka aws adk 2.0 for PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I am working on the integration of a jquery uploader plugin with aws s3.I found a example for it on the community  [wiki](https://github.com/sachintaware/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) .Now the  [example](https://s3.amazonaws.com/parsec_it_examples/s3-php.zip) is written in the old sdk and I no more find those functions in the latest one.I tried to search for a list of comparison(as to which replaced which) but didn't find any. 
                 I want to port the code to the new SDK as the Amazon guide itself says that they would be gradually moving towards using the new one.I would like to know if there's any list which comapares the two sdk's in terms of functions.
            I am looking for these functions specifically 
 `get_object_filesize`,`get_object_list`,`create_object` `delete_object`.

These are present in the plugin code which I need to change.
Also the plugin involves a lot of dependency(If I include one class I have to include an extended one or else each time). I want to reduce the dependency for the S3 class.Can anyone help me out with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, anything new should use the 2.x version of the SDK.

These links should help:

- [Migrating from SDK1 to SDK2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/index.html#migrating-from-sdk-1-to-sdk-2)
- [Amazon S3 User Guide (SDK2)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html)
- [listObjects()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects)
- [getObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObject)
- [putObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject)
- [deleteObject()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_deleteObject)

Comment: Thank you very much for the input,but if possible can you have a look at the example I shared and suggest how can I minimize the dependency?I worked on the old sdk and ended up including all the SDK utility files,which i believe shouldn't be needed just for file/image uploads.It would be a great favour to me being a newbie to this AWS world.

Comment: Hey I am not able to find the listObjects() function in my S3.php file.I checked on [GIT](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php) and its not their too!! Does getObject serve the same purpose?

Comment: The repository you have linked to is not the official AWS SDK for PHP.  The official SDK is located here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Comment: You should include the entire SDK as a general rule. Secondly, S3.php is NOT the official AWS SDK for PHP. You're using an unofficial, third-party class that only controls S3. You need to be sure you're using the right library.